# Is $r_2$ a uniformly at random value in $Z_n$, where $r_2=r_1 . m$

Tags: number-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $m$ be an arbitrary value in $Z_n$, where n is RSA modulo (n=p.q, where p and q are large primes). Then have: $r_2=r_1 . m$, where $r_1$ is a value chosen uniformly at random : $r_1\in Z^*_n$.

**Question : Is $r_2$ a uniformly at random value in $Z_n$?

Remark: Given n, it is hard to factorize n into p and q.

Comment: Hint: Since $m$ is arbitrarily chosen, suppose that you perversely chose $m = p$. Try it for the case $p=3, q=5$ which qualify as "large" primes since they are larger than the smallest prime. Is the set $\{3r_1 \bmod 15 \colon r_1 \in \mathbb Z_{15}\}$  the same set as $\{r_1 \colon r_1 \in \mathbb Z_{15}\}$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Would make any difference if the p and q are very large safe primes?

Comment: `Would make any difference if the p and q are very large safe primes?` Only if you renege on the promise that $m$ is an _arbitrary_ value in $\mathbb Z_n$ and insist on something simpler like $1 \leq m \leq 20$ or $m = 2^k, k \leq 8$ because this makes life easier for the person implementing the calculation.

Comment: Also asked two hours earlier (and answered in the comments there) on [crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/19735/819)

Comment: @DilipSarwate mathematicians describe (usually) more clear than cryptographers!

Comment: @DilipSarwate Consider RSA Blinding. A random value(raised to a power) is multiplied by a chiphertext to randomize it. Why canot say $r_2$ is blinded so it is randomly distributed value?http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinding_(cryptography)

Answer (score 2):

Stripped of the unnecessary notions regarding probability, the question is asking whether the
map $A_m: \mathbb Z_n^* \to \mathbb Z_n^*$ specified as 
$$A_m(r) \equiv m\cdot r \bmod ~ n, \quad m \in \mathbb Z_n^*$$ is a one-to-one map. If $m$ has a *multiplicative inverse* $m^{-1}$ in $\mathbb Z_n$, then $A_m(r)$ is a one-to-one map, and the the inverse
map is $A_{m^{-1}}(r)$. If $m$ does not have a multiplicative inverse, then
$A_m(r)$ is a many-to-one map and the inverse does not exist. For the special
case when $n = pq$ is the product of two primes $p$ and $q$, the multiples of $p$ and $q$ do not have multiplicative inverses. This holds even when the primes
are large or "safe" as the OP demands they must be.

Comment: To conclude if we pick $r_1$ uniformly at random in $Z_n$ such that $gcd(r_1,n)=1$ then $r_2$ is uniformly at random in $Z_n$. And there exists $r^{-1}_1$. I intentionally moved from $Z^*_n$ to $Z_n$ as the $m$ can only be defined (in my case)as: $m \in Z_n$.